# Changing Xml Build Action property programmatically in run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have to dynamically generate XML file using c#.

The problem I have is that the XML file is provided with Property "**Build Action**" as "**Content**".

I would like to change to "**Embedded Resource**" from "**Content**" in dynamically.

Does anyone know of this,please apply some basic XML formatting programmatically in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with out changing xml file properties to Embedded Resource.I enforced those dynamically generated .hbm.xml to NHibernate by using following code.Then I can able to bind this mapping files dynamically.

```
         Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
         cfg.Configure();
         string   file="@\\mappingfilesPath \\DynamicMappingfiles.hbm.xml";
         cfg.AddFile(new FileInfo(file));
         cfg.AddAssembly(this.GetType().Assembly);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the solution here

1. In the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio, click on the file you want to modify.
2. In the Properties windows, change the Build Action to Embedded Resource.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but I don't like to change manually for every dynamically created xml file.I would like to do it in programmatically .